# Unable to remove tags within a tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml

I have been using the following code to remove I-tags in P-tag. However, the `html_text` variable is expecting a string and I'm not sure how to convert the input accordingly. Here is the `remove_invalid_tags` function:

```
def remove_invalid_tags(html_text):
    print "HTML TEXT in REMOVE FUNCTION IS", html_text, type(html_text)
    invalid_tags = ['I']
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
    for tag in invalid_tags:
        for match in soup.findAll(tag):
            match.replaceWith('')
    print "RETURN STATEMENT INVALID TAGS", soup.get_text()
    return soup
```

And I'm trying to pass a "child2" variable which has the following tag, attributes, type respectively:

```
{}, (a),  P <class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>
```

How do I convert the the xml.etree.ElementTree.Element to the correct format that my function is expecting? When I send this variable, it works:

`"(a) <I>Competitive execution required; exceptions.</I> All purchases and sales"`

But, my element tree iteration isn't sending the correct format.

Comment: Your are passing the element object not text value. Can you post how you are calling function with parameter?

Comment: I'm iterating through a series of p-tags and passing the element to the function. 

for child2 in child1.iterfind('P)
    remove_invalid_tags(child2)

child2.text only sends "(a)" from the text. I'm not sure how to send the whole string so the function could remove the invalid tags.

Comment: So you use etree with BeautifulSoup? Can you post a snippet of html file and how you call function (not in comments but original post), so we can [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on our end?

Comment: I'll close this issue because I was able to figure out the solution. I appreciate everybody's help!